# Tree root removal under a slab of concrete

Tags: removal, tree, root

How do I remove tree roots (tree has been cut down)from under concrete and pavers on top of the concrete in my back yard? The pavers have lifted up and is extremely hazardous to my Mom and others.

What is the most inexpensive way to go?
Thanks for your time,April

Comment: Lift the pavers, pull the roots then re-lay the pavers.

Comment: Ignore the pavers for a moment ... how large are the concrete slabs and what is the condition of the concrete near the pavers?  The answer might be "lift it" (eg slabs up to perhaps sidewalk-size), or "smash it" (eg if the roots have already damaged it a lot).

Answer (score 1):

The least expensive way is probably to:

- rent a jackhammer and break up all the concrete yourself
- rent some sort of saw to cut through the roots
- rent a trailer (and maybe something to pull it) to haul all of the debris to the dump
- then buy and bring in some fill dirt to replace the roots you removed (maybe rent that trailer again)
- rent a plate compactor to ensure you've got a good solid base
- buy enough bags of concrete mix to replace the broken concrete you hauled out
- buy some wire mesh to reinforce the concrete
- mix the cement one bag at a time in a wheelbarrow with a hoe because you're looking for the *cheapest* option and that's less expensive than renting a cement mixer
- pour the concrete while someone mixes the next bag - you've got to have fresh concrete all the time or your new slab won't last
- finish the surface of the slab (if it's going to be covered by pavers again it doesn't need to be a super nice finish, but it needs to be reasonably level to make the paver job easier)

Of course, it may turn out to be cheaper to hire someone to do all this for you because this will also take a *lot* of time and your time is worth something, too. Oh, and you might just hurt yourself with all this manual labor, especially if you're not used to it. It may not come out as well as you'd like, especially if you've never done this before, and then it'll cost more to do it over.

This was all somewhat sarcastic...

Before looking at the *cheapest* way of doing it, be sure to factor in *all* the costs. Get a few estimates for the whole job, and ask to have it itemized by portion. Tell the contractors you're considering doing parts yourself so they can give you accurate pricing. It might cost a *bit* more to have someone else do *part* of the job than that portion would cost if they did the whole thing for you - be honest and up front with them, just like you want them to be honest & up front with you.

See what it would cost to have certain parts done for you then do the other parts yourself. (I've hired concrete work - excavation, pouring, finishing, etc. out 3 times now, even though I've done most of the rest of the construction myself.)

Once you've got these estimates from the pros - also ask about *how long* it'll take them to do it and the *number of people* they'll have on site (that tells you the number of total hours of labor they expect with experienced pros doing it), then determine what's the best way forward for you.

Comment: Having just had pavers removed and work done around foundations, just remember that your time will be 4 or 5 times as long as the professional.

Comment: Very true point, @SolarMike!

Answer (score 0):

Laying pawers is not rocket science, it is a DIY job.

Even if you are not DIY, you can pull the pawers one by one to reduce the cost of hiring someone.

Removing sand and crushed stone is labor intensive.

Cutting out the roots requires special tool.

Concrete removal is a different story. Very labor intensive,

When you ask for quote ask them to break it down in segments to see where you can DIY and save.

### Temporary fix

If the budget is a issue for now, you can fix it for $50.

Remove the pavers that are sticking out.

Fill the hole with special pawers-sand and compress with rubber hammer. Make the sand wet so it compresses better